# Dynamic MVC Model Server side validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dynamic

I have the following view:

```
@model dynamic
<form class="form-horizontal" id="formDynamicItem" action="/DynamicItem/SaveItem" method="post">

    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()


    <div class="col-xs-12 buttonBar">
        <button type="submit" value="Save" name="submitButton" class="btn">Save</button>

        <button type="submit" value="Cancel" name="submitButton" class="btn">Cancel</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="ibox ">
            <div class="ibox-content">
                @{
                    foreach (var obj in Model)
                    {
                        var kvpObj = (KeyValuePair<string, object>)obj;
                        var entityProp = (EntityAttributeProperties)kvpObj.Value;
                        <div class="form-group">
                            @if (entityProp.IsHiddenField)
                            {
                                <input type="hidden" class="form-control" data-val="true" id="@kvpObj.Key" name="@kvpObj.Key" value="@entityProp.Value" />
                            }
                            else if (entityProp.IsFormField)
                            {
                                var isReadOnly = entityProp.IsReadonly ? "readonly" : "";
                                IHtmlString validationRules = Html.Raw(string.Empty);
                                if (entityProp.ValidationRules != null)
                                {
                                    validationRules = entityProp.ValidationRules;
                                }

                                @Html.Label(entityProp.Name, new { @class = labelClass })
                                <div class="@controlClass">
                                    @switch (@entityProp.Type)
                                    {
                                        //... many cases


                                        default:
                                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="@kvpObj.Key" name="@kvpObj.Key" value="@entityProp.Value" @isReadOnly @validationRules />
                                            break;
                                    }
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>




@section Scripts {
    <script>
        $("#formDynamicItem").validate();
    </script>
}
```

And in the controller I get my values using FormCollection:

```
public ActionResult SaveItem(FormCollection form)
        {
         ...
         newValue = typeConverter.ConvertFromString(form[entityAttribute.Name]);
         ...                                                   
         }    
   }
```

My question is the following:

How can I establish Server-side validation on such dynamic model? Can I use FormCollection somehow? Possibly build dynamic view model somehow? If anyone has experience in this please consider giving a suggestion(answer).

**Update: Making Detail page with ViewModel insted of dynamic model**

So, After much refactoring I appear to be again stuck with server-side validation:

So now I have this ViewModel:

```
public class DynamicItemViewModel
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public List<EntityAttributeProperties> Properties { get; set; }
}
```

this detail page:

```
@model ExactDistillation.Models.DynamicItem.DynamicItemViewModel
<div class="wrapper wrapper-content animated fadeInRight">
    <div class="row">
        @using (Html.BeginForm("SaveItem", "DynamicItem", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", @id = "formDynamicItem" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

            @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Id)
            <div class="col-xs-12 buttonBar">
                <button type="submit" value="Save" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Save</button>

                <button type="submit" value="Cancel" name="submitButton" class="btn btn-default pull-right cancel">Cancel</button>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <div class="ibox float-e-margins">
                    <div class="ibox-title text-webwonders">
                        <h5>Item</h5>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ibox-content">
                        @{
                            for (int i = 0; i < Model.Properties.Count; i++)
                            {
                                @Html.EditorFor(m => Model.Properties[i], "EntityAttributeProperties", "Properties[" + i + "]")
                            }
                        }
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          }
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is how I define EntityAttributeProperties page:

```
@model EntityAttributeProperties

<div class="form-group">
    @if (Model.IsHiddenField)
    {
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.Value)
    }
    else if (Model.IsFormField)
    {
        @Html.Label(Model.Name, new { @class = "col-sm-5 col-md-4 col-lg-3" })

        <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-8 col-lg-9">
            @switch (Model.Type)
            {
                --- Many cases

                default:
                    @Html.DynamicTextBoxFor(m => m.Value, null, Model.IsReadonly, Model.ValidationRules)
                    break;

            }
        </div>
    }
</div>
```

EntityAttributesProperties looks the following way:

```
public class EntityAttributeProperties
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }
    public object Value { get; set; }
    public EntityAttributeDataTypeEnum Type { get; set; }
    public short Order { get; set; }
    public bool IsFormField { get; set; }
    public bool IsReadonly { get; set; }
    public bool IsHiddenField { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string,object> ValidationRules { get; set; }
}
```

So, I am trying to make server-side validation for Model, but I am stuck, because I don't find any elegant solution to my problem, just solutions in which I have to do a lot of hardcoding (which I don't like).

Here is how I receive the form Submit:

```
 public ActionResult SaveItem(DynamicItemViewModel model)
        {
            List<EntityAttributeExtendedView> entityAttributes = GetItemEntityAttributes();
            DataObject dataObject = _dbContext.DataObjectCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == model.Id);

            if (dataObject != null)
            {
                JObject json = JObject.Parse(dataObject.Value);
                dynamic dynJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(dataObject.Value);

                // Possibly loop through all entity attributes and separately make a custom validation ?
                // Or somehow create custom Model State for validation ?

            }
            return View("Detail", model);


        }
```

I will appreciate any suggestion on how to approach the problem with server side validation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm adding another Answer because the Question changed heavily.

A good approach is to use the `IValidatableObject` Interface. So you add this Interface to your `EntityAttributeProperties` class and have to override the Method `Validate`. for simple validation like required fields, you use so called validation Attributes.

Your `EntityAttributeProperties` class would be decorated like this:

```
public class EntityAttributeProperties : IValidatableObject
{
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public object Value { get; set; }

    ...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        var results = new List<ValidationResult>();
        if (... /* some condition, e.g. specific EntityAttributeDataTypeEnum */)
        {
            // Do some validation

            // some other random test
            if (.../* something not right... */)
            {
                results.Add(new ValidationResult("your input was not valid!"));
            }
        }

        return results;
    }
}
```

You *might* need to also make your `DynamicItemViewModel` and `IValidatableObject` and loop through the Items, but sometimes MVC is smart enough to validate sub-items automatically, so you *might* need this:

```
 public class DynamicItemViewModel : IValidatableObject
{
    ...

    public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        return Items.SelectMany(x => x.Validate(validationContext));
    }
}
```

OK now in your Controller, you basically need to check your [`ModelState`](https://www.exceptionnotfound.net/asp-net-mvc-demystified-modelstate/). The automatically generated `ModelState` Property contains all errors.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have to do much more work but you navigated me in to the correct approach :)

Answer (score 2):

`FormCollection` is a very raw form of data and cannot be validated easily. I'd suggest you should refactor your view to be able to use ViewModels, else you will have a hard time working with the Data.

I cannot show you the full way but give you some hints:

1. Create a single View Model class for the View which contains a list of `Items` (of type `EntityAttributeProperties`). Let's call it `MainViewModel`.
2. Pass this View Model to the view rather then the Dictionary
3. In your view, use `@Html.EditoFor(x => x.Items)` to generate the correct HTML. ASP.NET MVC will use the Editor Templates for `EntityAttributeProperties` type
4. This is a good moment to create a new view `EntityAttributeProperties.cshtml` in your View folders `EditorTemplates` sub-folder
5. within this item view, you can do all your `entityProp.Type` switches, but be careful with ID generation, always use `@Html.IdFor(...)`  etc. instead of generating own IDs to keep type safe with your View Model
6. After some tweaks, your Post Action should be able to receive your view model of Type `MainViewModel`. If everything went good, the Item's will be filled, even if you used different Controls (hidden fields, text fields, drop-downs...) to populate the Values

From my perspective, only this MVC-safe approach will lead to success in this case

Comment: Thank you for this response I will give it a try and update the thread afterwards

Comment: I updated my question, if you have time please take a look. Thanks.

Comment: @LyubomirDimov I like your new approach, I think it's close to what I have suggested